# JqueryUI menubar shows white text in cupertino theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menubar

I'm starting to use Jquery UI. I particularly like the cupertino theme and I need to build a horizontal menu.

1st problem I faced is that it seems menubar is not part of the JqueryUI (removed or in development?) so I had to add it on top of `jquery-ui.js`.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom\css\cupertino\jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\jquery.ui.menubar.css" />

  <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom\js\jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom\js\jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="\js\jquery.ui.menubar.js"></script>
```

It seems that it's not 100% compatible with the rest of JqueryUI, because the sub menu have white text on a very light background.

Question: Have I to modify the style of the `li` elements manually (besides I was unsuccessful) or is there something conceptually wrong in my usage of JqueryUI+menubar? [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/Wpn5g/)

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code in jquery.ui.menubar.js.  No need to make any css changes.

```
// line 386, from
.closest(this.options.items).removeClass("ui-state-active");
// to
.closest(this.options.items).removeClass("ui-widget-header");

// line 408, from
menuItem.addClass( "ui-state-active" );
// to
menuItem.addClass("ui-widget-header");
this.menuItems.children().addClass("ui-widget-header");
```

I tested this with the following themes:

1. cupertino
2. flick
3. le frog
4. smoothness
5. start
6. sunny
7. swanky purse

It worked well with all.  I tested it using IE10 (and in compatibility mode) and in Chrome 30.0.1599.101.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The white color comes from the following lines, 862 to 867, of `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css` (cupertino theme)

```
.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Now while in `menu()` the `.ui-state-active` is assigned to the `a` element inside the `li` of the top menu, in `menubar()` thi active state is assigned **DIRECTLY** to the `li` element causing **every** `a` element to have white text. (and in cupertino this make the text and readable!!)

So, to fix this we can change the two line in `jquery.ui.menubar.js` where the above class is added and removed:

```
// line 408, from
menuItem.addClass( "ui-state-active" );
// to
menuItem.children(":first").addClass( "ui-state-active" );

// line 386, from
.closest( this.options.items ).removeClass( "ui-state-active" );
// to
.closest( this.options.items ).children(":first").removeClass( "ui-state-active" );
```

I tried to update the fiddle loading the js in my **[google drive](https://googledrive.com/host/0B_fCj70p203gTVpyVGVuQkNXVjA)** but jsfiddle doesn't load it.